# Get items from SPO and past them in Azure SQL with Azure Logic App

Tags: sql, json, azure, sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to make a logic app with "Recurrence" triger which get items from SPO list (from view) with condition:

- if have null values, then pass them some string or boolean (if column is boolean type)

Then get rows from Azure SQL table and compare with data from SPO (above), if there is a match then skip them, if is not a match then add row in Azure SQL with values from SPO item.

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Have you tried doing this? If so, what are the errors or blockers you are facing?

Comment: @SwethaKandikonda yes, basicaly I made Recurrence triger, then Get Items (SPO), Get Items (SQL) and For Each loop which take every item from SPO list and set to SQL value., but this does not work for me (because null values which some items has).

Answer (score 0):

Work is done ! With Execute a SQL query (V2) I am getting values from dtb. and with expression from condition `length(string(body('Execute_a_SQL_query_(V2)_2')?['resultsets']))` I now if item which I want to add is already in database.
With another Execute a SQL query (V2) I can add specific values.